# Is it grammatically correct to convey information in this way when translating information from a table into prose?

Tags: commas, semicolons

All three companies were offered discount in 2020 (Company A, 10%; Company B, 12%; Company C, 10%).

Comment: 'Grammar' doesn't really apply to such structures. Is your example _acceptable_? Totally ... it's easily understood, tidy, and uses a parenthetical detailing (in this case) the different levels of discount in a normal way. A single dash could be used to offset instead, but the brackets seem stylistically better in this case. The 'super-comma' use of the semicolon in lists needing other commas (and I'd say this one does) is unremarkable nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Company A, 10%; Company B, 12%; Company C, 10%" is fine, using semicolons to group items within the list, and then commas within the parts separated by semicolons. (There are other ways to write it, e.g. with two lists and the word "respectively", but using semicolons is probably the clearest.)

[Here's a link to a BBC Bitesize grammar article and video](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/zr6bxyc/articles/zhntng8) which gives the example of listing members of a band: "My dream band would be: Bruce, vocals; Stephanie, guitar and backing vocals; Davide, bass; Neeko, drums."